# Is there a plan to update gmail add ons to comply with Material design 2.0?

Tags: material-design, gmail-addons

Since the launch of the new gmail , which of course complies with Material design 2, I expected gmail add ons too would comply with the same. However , google default add ons such as - calendar , and tasks use MD 2.

Will other gmail add-ons too have the latest material design ? May be in the near future ?

Answer (score 0):

@Hari Balaji!

Probably they will.

Take a look at their GApps update blog here:

- https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/